# share one remote mac with multiple mouses and keyboards

Tags: macos

Does such solutions exist ? It's for collaborative training purpose.

I searched and all I found is "Share one Mouse and Keyboard with Multiple Computers" which is not what I'm looking for since it's the other way round and remotely (on cloud/hosting).

Comment: I would think that a number of remote control applications, like VNC would allow multiple people to connect and control the computer at the same time.

Comment: Please can you describe your use case a little better so we can understand your scenario?